# What does the term $\mathcal O(\epsilon^2)$ mean?

Tags: definition, notation, perturbation-theory, approximations, asymptotics

In the highest upvoted answer to [Where does the $i$ come from in the Schrödinger equation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/238389/where-does-the-i-come-from-in-the-schr%c3%b6dinger-equation) 
the author writes the following equation:

$$ U^\dagger U=(\mathbb I+\epsilon^* A^\dagger)(\mathbb I+\epsilon A)=I+\epsilon^*A^\dagger+\epsilon A+\mathcal O(\epsilon^2) $$

What does that last term mean? It looks a lot like the [big O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) from asymptotic analysis.

Comment: $O(\epsilon^2)$ is big O notation from asymptotic analysis. Why would you think otherwise?

Answer (score 3):

$\mathcal O(\epsilon^2)$ just means *of order $\epsilon^2$* i.e. terms that are proportional to $\epsilon^2$.

The point is that is $\epsilon$ is much less than unity then $\epsilon^2 \ll \epsilon$, so terms proportional to $\epsilon^2$ and higher powers can be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is the big $O$ notation, but here we are dealing with operators and not numbers, so that a further interpretation needs. It means that there is a constant $C>0$ such that  $$ ||U^\dagger U - (I+\epsilon^*A^\dagger+\epsilon A) || \leq C|\epsilon|^2$$
if $|\epsilon |\leq  E$ for some constant $E$.
Actually, regirously speaking, the initial statement is false if $A$ is not bounded. In that case the correct statement has a more delicate form related to the strong-operator topology instead of the norm topology.