# What does the notation $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)$ mean?

Tags: definition, notation, approximations, asymptotics

I was reading a text about quantum scattering, and I faced a notation I don't understand. The equation is the following:
$$
\nabla \psi_{\text{scattered}} = \frac{i k f(\theta) e^{ikr}}{r} \mathbf{\hat{r}} + \mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)
$$
and I do not know the meaning of the $\mathcal{O}\left(\frac{1}{r^2}\right)$ portion.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/495470/2451

Answer (score 3):

It is a common notation in computer science, mostly used in asymptotic complexity. The definition can be found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Informally, it means that the quantity $\nabla \psi_{\text{scattered}}$, when $r$ goes to infinity, is equal to $\frac{ikf(\theta)e^{ikr}}{r}$ plus some unknown function $g$ that does not grow quicker than the function $r \mapsto \frac{1}{r^2}$.

From another viewing point, for **very large $r$** (the very large is essential), if you approximate $\nabla \psi_{\text{scattered}}$ with $\frac{ikf(\theta)e^{ikr}}{r}$, you know that the error will not grow faster than $\frac{1}{r^2}$.

Comment: Thanks Nelimee. Your answer was really helpful:)